# How to join two or multiple table behalf of min value and and date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I have to join these tables on `GID` (which is group id)

**Tables are Here**

```
         Table 1                           Table 2        
+-------------------------+       +-----------------------+
|  GID  |   Amt | Tag     |       |  GID  |   Date        |
+-------------------------+       +-----------------------+
|   A   |   20  | TAG_01  |       |   A   |   2016-09-10  |
|   A   |   15  | TAG_02  |       |   A   |   2016-09-18  |
|   A   |   10  | TAG_03  |       |   B   |   2016-09-10  |
|   A   |   25  | TAG_04  |       |   B   |   2016-09-11  |
|   A   |   30  | TAG_05  |       |   B   |   2016-09-12  |
|   B   |   80  | TAG_06  |       |   C   |   2016-10-12  |
|   B   |   40  | TAG_07  |       |   C   |   2016-10-13  |
|   B   |   20  | TAG_08  |       |   C   |   2016-10-14  |
|   B   |   60  | TAG_09  |       |   D   |   2016-09-10  |
|   B   |   100 | TAG_10  |       |   D   |   2016-10-13  |
|   C   |   6   | TAG_11  |       +-----------------------+     
|   C   |   3   | TAG_12  |           
|   C   |   12  | TAG_13  |           
|   C   |   9   | TAG_14  |           
|   C   |   15  | TAG_15  |           
|   D   |   10  | TAG_16  |           
|   D   |   7   | TAG_17  |           
|   D   |   13  | TAG_18  |           
|   D   |   16  | TAG_19  |           
|   D   |   19  | TAG_20  |           
|   D   |   22  | TAG_21  |           
+-------------------------+
```

I have to join this table on `GID` but `Amt` should be minimum or lowest of each group and where date is a parameter too in where clause

**For example**

All Group on Date = 2016-09-10,
So Result should show like this

```
         Desired Result          
+-------------------------+
|  GID  |  Amt  |   Tag   |
+-------------------------+
|   A   |   10  | TAG_03  |
|   B   |   20  | TAG_08  |
|   D   |   7   | TAG_17  |
+-------------------------+
```

But Result is showing like this, it change only on MIN(Amt) not working on other column so tag data is each group's first row 
Here is result

```
   Current Result (Error)          
+-------------------------+
|  GID  |  Amt  |   Tag   |
+-------------------------+
|   A   |   10  | TAG_01  |
|   B   |   20  | TAG_06  |
|   D   |   7   | TAG_16  |
+-------------------------+
```

What is should be query for this does any one know this
Thanks in advance.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/717ea)

Comment: Where's the sqlfiddle/rextester?

Comment: actually i don't know sqlfiddle i tested on localhost mysql

Comment: Time to get to know it I guess.

Comment: here is sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/717ea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM table1 x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT t1.gid, MIN(t1.amt) amt 
         FROM table1 t1
         JOIN table2 t2
           ON t2.gid = t1.gid
        WHERE t2.date = '2016-09-10'
        GROUP
           BY gid ) y
    ON y.gid = x.gid
   AND y.amt = x.amt;

+------+------+--------+
| gid  | amt  | tag    |
+------+------+--------+
| A    |   10 | TAG_03 |
| B    |   20 | TAG_08 |
| D    |    7 | TAG_17 |
+------+------+--------+
```

http://rextester.com/PEEGCN40996

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the matching tags on a given date by doing:

```
select t1.gid, t1.amt, t1.tag
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.gid = t1.gid
where t2.date = '2016-09-10' ;
```

If you want the tag with the minimum amount on that date, then I would suggest the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` hack:

```
select t1.gid, min(t1.amt) as amt,
       substring_index(group_concat(t1.tag order by amt), ',', 1) as tag_minamt
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.gid = t1.gid
where t2.date = '2016-09-10' 
group by t1.gid;
```

I should note that `table2` only appears to be used to filter the rows by date.  If that is not necessary, then the `where` approach can also work:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.amt = (select min(tt1.amt) from t1 tt1 where tt1.gid = t1.gid);
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**:

```
SELECT x.gid, x.amt, x.tag
FROM table1 x
INNER JOIN (
    select a.gid, MIN(a.amt) amt, 
    from table1 a
    inner join table2 b on a.gid = b.gid
    WHERE a.date = '2016-12-12'
    GROUP BY a.gid ) d ON d.gid = x.gid AND d.amt = x.amt
```